# MySQL: Simple queries hang

Tags: mysql, vpn

after having fiddled around for quite a few days now, I decided to put up my fist posting on SO ever:

I have a MySQL server in a VPN. It's possible to connect using a client running on the server machine and everything's fine.

If I try to connect from another machine within the VPN, it's possible to authentcate and get to the MySQL prompt. But doing a SELECT hangs. First try was to investigate the processlist, which shows the process as "Sleeping". Second try was to do a dump, but this hangs after the first few lines. When I stop the server, it says:

```
-- Connecting to 192.168.111.150...
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 192.168.111.150    Database: mydb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.1.66-0+squeeze1-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

and the hangs. Killing the server leads to:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when using LOCK TABLES
```

What is going on here? And what can I do next?

Thx in advance,

Thorsten

Comment: Probably another query has a lock on that table you are querying. Investigate the processlist as the/a SUPER user....

Comment: The processlist says:

`| Id | User | Host                  | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |

+----+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 39 | root | 192.168.111.151:46990 | mydb | Sleep   |  142 |       | NULL             |

| 52 | root | localhost             | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |`

Comment: Hm, anything in the logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing. It just falls asleep...

Comment: Funny enough, it works when it's running in the outside world, so a direct connection to the server's IP-address (without VPN) works fine. Possibly sth in the firewalling?

Comment: Hm. Could be.. but why would this allow a login but no further data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a few more hours and encountering problems with VNC, I finally found the solution: The MTU for the VPN-interface ppp0 was too high (1500). Obviously this not only can lead to a blank screen in VNC connections, but also to trouble with MySQL traffic. Throttling it down to 768 did the trick. Now it works like a charm :-)

Comment: I had same problem(SELECT hang) and i also found that the MTU caused it! do you has any reference why the MTU makes the problem? regards!